# WPF: ListView with Images from a folder

Tags: wpf, image, listview

I'm sort of new to WPF, but I have to do this and it's taking a lot of my time. I've searched for a solution but there are many alternative solutions and I honestly don't understand most of this. I have this XAML code:

```
<ListView Name="Thumbnails">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" Height="30" Width="30" Margin="5"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

As well as this codebehind:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) + @"\SlikeSportista\");
    FileInfo[] images = folder.GetFiles("*.jpg");
    foreach (FileInfo img in images)
    {
        Thumbnails.Items.Add(img);
    }
}
```

I've also tried this line of code in the foreach loop:

```
Thumbnails.Items.Add(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(img.FullName));
```

In both cases the items are added, but the images are not displayed correctly, or rather, at all. You can select them, and there are the same amount of elements as there are in the folder, but there is no display.

Another question (less important one) would be how to display the images in squares instead of rows. Basically I want to have about 4 or so images per row, but now I have only 1 element per row, stretched all the way (although I can't see what is being displayed).

Comment: Rather than use Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName wouldn't it be easier to use a relative path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first attempt, you're adding `FileInfo` objects to the ListView's items collections. These aren't automatically converted to [`ImageSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource.aspx) items, as required by the binding in your DataTemplate. Add the FileInfo's `FullName` instead:

```
foreach (FileInfo img in images)
{
    Thumbnails.Items.Add(img.FullName);
}
```

In your second attempt the problem is that you add instances of `System.Drawing.Image`, which is not part of WPF, but WinForms, and will also not be converted automatically. You may use [`BitmapImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) instead:

```
foreach (FileInfo img in images)
{
    Thumbnails.Items.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri(img.FullName)));
}
```

The difference between both solutions is that in the second one you manually create image objects, whereas the first one relies on automatic conversion from `string` to `ImageSource`, which is built into WPF as a TypeConverter.

---

A solution for your second question would be to replace the ListView's [`ItemsPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx), perhaps by a [`UniformGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms612624.aspx):

```
<ListView Name="Thumbnails">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="4"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    ...
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was quite helpful. Not only did it solve my problem, but it also helped me better understand why there was a problem in the first place (after examining the functions a bit more). Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you should keep in mind that adding images in the code-behind file (.xaml.cs file) is bad practice. In WPF there is a very widely used and common design pattern called MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) which you should familiarize with and use. In your case, you should have had a ViewModel class containing an `IEnumerable<BitmapImage>` property that contains the images you wish to display in your `ListView`.

For example, let's say your ViewModel class is called ImagesViewModel and your view is ImagesView:

**ImagesViewModel** will have a property called:

`ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> Images`

**ImagesView** will contain:

```
<ListView Name="Thumbnails" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <UniformGrid Columns="4"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
...
```

Now, if you add / remove images to Images, they will be automatically added / removed from your list view (you have to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your view model and you're done).